# Finding the coordinates on a circle given it’s part of a tangent

Tags: geometry

[image]

There are many parts to the question. The first asks you to find an equation for circle $C_2$, given it has a centre $(10,0)$ and a radius of $3$. This answer is $(x-10)^2+y^2=9$.

We are then told that $ABP$ is a tangent to both circles and cuts the $x$ axis at $P$ and asks us to find the coordinates of $P$, which the answer is $(15,0)$.

This is where I am a bit confused. The question says ‘a line through $P$ has gradient $m$. Write down, in terms of $m$, the equation of this line’. I think this answer is just $y=mx-15m$.

We are then told that this line cuts circle $C_1$ in two places and the $x$-coordinates of these two points satisfy the equation:

$$x^2(1+m^2)-30m^2x+(225m^2-81)=0$$

Hence determine the coordinates of the point $A$. I am not sure how to find these coordinates.

Comment: If $m$ is the gradient (also called slope, right?) then the equation of the line is of the form $y=mx+b$. Since the point $P=(15,0)$ is in this line, it should satisfy this equation. Then your equation is actually $y=mx-15m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u$ be the first coordinate of $P$. Then the Intercept Theorem gives $(u-10)/u=3/9$, from where $u=15$.

Pythagoras shows the $AP$ has length $12$.  Now use the fact that for right-angled triangles its doubled area is the product of their catheti as well as the product of the hypotenuse and the height $h$, which here is the second coordinate of $A$.  Hence from $15h=9\cdot12$ we arrive in $h=7.2$.  Now plug that in the equation of $C_1$ to get $5.4$ for the first coordinate.

*Even easier.*  If $A(x_0,y_0)$ is a point on $x^2+y^2=r^2$, the tangent's equation in $A$ is given by
$xx_0+yy_0=r^2.$

Proof: Excluding the trivial case $y_0=0$ the tangent's slope is $-x_0/y_0$, it follows that its equation is
$$\frac{y-y_0}{x-x_0}=\frac{-x_0}{y_0}\iff
yy_0-y_0^2=x_0^2-xx_0\iff xx_0+yy_0=x_0^2+y_0^2.$$
Now notice that $x_0^2+y_0^2=r^2.$
Obviously the equation holds in the case $y_0=0$, too.
$\quad\square$

We know that $P(15,0)$ is a point of the tangent in $A(x_0,y_0)$; from there 
$$15\cdot x_0+0\cdot y_0=81$$
it follows that $x_0=81/15$.

Comment: Could you please explain how you get this polar equation?

Comment: Let $(x-x_m)^2+(y-y_m)^2=r^2$ and $P(p_1,p_2)$.  Then the polar is given by the equation  $$(x-p_1)(x-x_m)+(y-p_1)(y-x_m)=r^2.$$

Comment: Using this method, could we just find point B on the diagram by using the same equation but replacing the 81 with the 9.

Answer (score 0):

Let the equation of the line be $y = mx + c$.

We know the distance of this line from two points vis-a-vis the centers of the two circles.

1. Distance from $(0,0)$ is $9$:

$$\frac{c^2}{1+m^2} = 81$$

2. Distance from $(10,0)$ is $3$:

$$\frac{(10m + c)^2}{1+m^2} = 9$$

Solve for $m$ and $c$.

Edit:

Here I have used the fact that the distance between a point $(x_1,y_1)$ from a line $ax+by+c = 0$ is given by:

$$d = \left|\frac{ax_1+by_1+c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right|$$

Comment: However, this does not use the information given in the previous part, so how would you use: x²(1+m²)-30m²x+(225m²-81)=0 as the question puts emphasis on ‘hence’ so expects the use of this answer?

Comment: You weren't able to find the coordinates of the common tangent with the x-axis right?

Comment: I am unable to find the coordinates of the point A

Comment: Yeah so first you need to find the equation of the tangent

Comment: I don’t understand where you are getting those two equations from that you have stated in your answer.

Comment: Distance between a point $(x_1,y_1)$ from a line $ax+by+c = 0$ is given by $\left|\frac{ax_1+by_1+c}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}\right|$.

Comment: Oh really that’s cool, is that a theorem, if so what’s it called?

Comment: Yes and I have just squared the sides to remove the modulus. For a proof you can Google it and will find plenty of links.

Comment: Ok, so I found that c=11.25 and m=-0.75, therefore the equation of the tangent is y=-0.75x+11.25, but how do you use this to find the coordinates of A?

Comment: Now note that two lines (with slope $m_1$ and $m_2$ )are perpendicular to each other if and only if $m_1 \times m_2 = -1$. So you can find the equation of line $AO$ by using the fact that it passes through $(0,0)$ and that it has slope $4/3$.

Comment: $c=11.25$ doesn't look right to me. Because the center of the second circle is at $(10,0)$ and it has radius $3$, so $c > 13$

Comment: Oh I see, so you find the intersection between the lines AO and AP to get the values x=5.4 and y=7.2. Thanks, that seems to be the answer, however this requires knowledge of the equation between a distance and a point, which we would not have known.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the following is what the problem-writer intended you to do: When the line through $P$ is tangent to the circle, there’s only one intersection, in which case the polynomial $x^2(1+m^2)-30m^2x+(225m^2-81)$ only has one root. Set the discriminant $-36(16m^2-9)$ to zero and solve for $m$. There will be two solutions; choose the negative value, since the line slopes downward. Substitute this value into the equation for $x$ and solve that equation, then compute the corresponding value of $y$ from the equation of the circle.

However, as [Michael Hoppe’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3239178/265466) points out, since you likely already worked out the equation of the tangent line when you computed $P$, it’s much easier to compute its pole. Even if you hadn’t, after finding $m$ for the tangent line, it’s much less work to compute its pole that to solve all of those additional quadratic equations above.

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering about this. The previous parts encourage you to find the value of P by considering similar triangles, so would would not necessarily be easier to calculate the tangents. However, one thing that still bugs me is that discriminants don’t form part of the syllabus that this problem comes from, so I wonder if this is this intended solution?

Comment: Maybe not, then. I should think that being able to solve quadratic equations and understanding how to determine the number of solutions would be a prerequisite for this course.